# Revert reference to System.Web.Mvc back to version 3.0.0.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I received an ASP.NET MVC application that needs to be modified which uses System.Web.Mvc version 3.0.0.0. But when I copied the files on my dev machine, I noticed that my reference to System.Web.Mvc was broken. So my first instinct was to delete the reference and add it back, which worked fine. My application compiles. But I noticed after this change that it now references version 3.0.0.1.

Here's the problem: The client's production server has version 3.0.0.0 so when I deploy it on the server I get an error saying it cannot find 3.0.0.1.

How can I change my development machine to use System.Web.Mvc version 3.0.0.0 so that when I deploy to production, I don't get this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft released [Microsoft Security Bulletin MS14-059](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/security/ms14-059.aspx), which was a security issue so critical that they broke backward compatibility with previous versions of MVC 3 and 4. And as the issue was critical, there is no way to revert a machine back to 3.0.0.0.

However, this also makes it so a project that works with MVC 3.0.0.1 does not compile on a machine with MVC 3.0.0.0 installed. This will completely remove MVC 3.0.0.0 which was installed into the Global Assembly Cache.

MVC 3.0.0.1 on the other hand is deployed via NuGet, and you will need to add a reference to it and recompile with it in order for the patch to work (if you haven't done so already).

## Best Solution

The correct solution is to install [the patch](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7d07b199-e7b6-4526-930c-cea52dc15b95) on the target machine.

## A Possible Alternative

However, if that machine (or your build server) is out of your control, the following hack will make your project compile on machines that both have the patch and those that don't.

1. Right-click on your project node in solution explorer (the one that references MVC 3), and click "Unload Project".
2. Right-click on it again and choose "Edit ".
3. Locate the reference to `System.Web.Mvc` and replace it with the elements below.
4. Save the project file.
5. Right-click on the project node again and click "Reload Project".

---

```
<!-- Due to the windows update MS14-059, we need this hack to ensure we can 
build MVC3 both on machines that have the update and those that don't -->
<Reference Condition=" Exists('$(windir)\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll') " Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
<Reference Condition=" !Exists('$(windir)\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll') " Include="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <Private>True</Private>
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.3.0.20105.1\lib\net40\System.Web.Mvc.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
```

Note that you need to have the [MVC NuGet package installed for version 3.0.20105.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/3.0.20105.1) for the above to work, or you will need to adjust the version number as appropriate to match the version you have.

Comment: My I.T. guy gave me full access to the Windows Server 2012 since my MVC3 app is the first to be deployed on that machine. I decided to put System.Web.Mvc version 3.0.0.1 in my bin folder. The application at least starts, I get the home page, etc. But when I start clicking on some links I get runtime errors saying "Could not load file or assembly..." and they are not references to System.Web.Mvc.

Comment: MVC 3.0.0.0 was installed by an installer and went into the global assembly cache, which is different from 3.0.0.1, which is deployed by NuGet. Installing [the patch](https://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=7d07b199-e7b6-4526-930c-cea52dc15b95) will uninstall 3.0.0.0 completely from the machine. You also need to ensure that the `.csproj` files all have the reference updated to 3.0.0.1, and the project has been compiled against it before deployed.

Comment: I installed the file AspNetMVC3.msi from the link you provided. As you said, that replaced the 3.0.0.0 with 3.0.0.1. I recompiled, now it works fine. You're a star NightOwl888 !!! Thanks! This is the answer.